# Printing multi-page PDF with different copies of each page in Acrobat

Tags: pdf, print-design, workflow, adobe-acrobat

I have a PDF with 20-30 pages. I want to print them but with different numbers of copies for each page. Right now I'm using Acrobat Reader. I know I can do this manually by selecting the page in the thumbnail list and chose number of copies.

But I want to do it automatically, something like this:

```
1*12, 2*7, 3*15
```

Maybe it's possible to script printing?

My first plan was to make 12 pages of page 1 and 7 pages of page 2 etc and then print all, but that didn't work well when printing since each page is heavy with vector graphics and it had to send each page to the printer = slooow.

Oh and I'm using Windows 7 when printing.

Comment: Is it always the same number of the same page, or is that variable from printout to printout?

Comment: It varies from printout to printout.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like:

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3
```

if you want something like:

```
1*12, 2*7, 3*15
```

I think that's the best way without any software to do this.

Comment: I will try this. I'm just worried that the software will send page one 12 times to the printer instead of telling the printer to print page one 12 times.

Comment: Let me know how it works out. I'm quite interested and I'm not sure how to check on that.

Comment: Nope, it didn't work. Acrobat was sending the page 1 over and over. I need to figure out something else.

Comment: You could print it once and then copy it using a copy machine. Or you just wait til it sends all documents. Maybe it's faster than waiting here for a good answer

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Acrobat doesn't let you set the settings for a print job when creating a new Action. One way You could print the least number of pages. You would need to create one print job for each number of copies you need.

Example: To print

```
1*12, 2*7, 3*15, 4*15
```

1. In the thumbnail view, select all pages, and then right-click and select Print Pages (Note: You can just do <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd> instead and manually enter the page range--faster than using the thumbnails if you're quick with the keyboard).
2. Make the number of copies 7
3. Repeat, but only with pages 1, 3, and 4 selected
4. Print 5 copies
5. Repeat, but only with pages 3 and 4
6. Print 3 copies

This may (or may not) be more ideal than just printing the required number of copies of each back from the outset....

Answer (score 0):

If this is going to be a recurring process you can try saving the selected pages as a new pdf so you will have different pdfs of the intended pages.

Comment: That was already mentioned by the op to be not a solution because printing is too slow ...